# Render a texture in OpenGL ES 2 using a colormap array

Tags: c, opengl-es

I´m trying to render a map raster image as a texture in OpenGL. The original image file pixel format is a single byte and have their RGB values in a 256x3 bytes colormap (R,G,B). 
I can correctly render the image performing the color mapping and generating RGB pixels in the CPU, then loading as texture in OpenGL.
However I'd like to have the fragment shader do that. 
As I'm currently using OpenGL ES , I'm loading the colormap as a 256x1 2D texture (1D are not supported).
However I'm getting a wrong color rendering (all red or some hint of image all in red). 
I can have a render in very raw black-white assigning fragColor = texture(ourTexture, texCoord).rrr so the image texture loading seems fine;

Here's the fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es                              
precision mediump float;                     
in vec2 texCoord;                            
out vec4 fragColor;                          
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;                
uniform sampler2D colormap;                  
void main() {                                
float color =texture(ourTexture, texCoord).r;  
fragColor = texture(colormap, vec2(color,0.0)); 
}
```

Here's the colormap texture initialization

```
glGenTextures(1, &render.colormapTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, render.colormapTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
        256, 1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &render.geoData.colormap[0]);
```

Here's the raster image initialization:

```
glGenTextures(1, &cache.cache[i].texture.texID); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cache.cache[i].texture.texID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

and pixel loading somewhere else

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tile->texture->texID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED,
             tile->texture->width,
             tile->texture->height, 0, GL_RED,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             tile->texture->texData);
```

Here's the drawing code:

```
glBindVertexArray(render.grid.terrainGrid[i][j].vao);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
               render.grid.terrainGrid[i][j].texture->texID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, render.colormapTexture);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
```

this is a formatted printout of the colormap as it gets loaded as texture:

```
[0]->r:0 g:0 b:0 
[1]->r:255 g:255 b:255 
[2]->r:0 g:0 b:2 
[3]->r:252 g:252 b:254 
[4]->r:111 g:18 b:20 
[5]->r:80 g:18 b:19 
[6]->r:205 g:59 b:60 
[7]->r:145 g:16 b:20 
[8]->r:207 g:176 b:177 
[9]->r:142 g:48 b:53 
[10]->r:81 g:47 b:49 
[11]->r:175 g:48 b:57 
[12]->r:113 g:48 b:53 
[13]->r:176 g:15 b:36 
[14]->r:176 g:141 b:147 
[15]->r:132 g:116 b:119 
[16]->r:46 g:16 b:23 
[17]->r:176 g:18 b:63 
[18]->r:144 g:18 b:54 
[19]->r:153 g:41 b:78 
[20]->r:248 g:200 b:216 
[21]->r:113 g:20 b:54 
[22]->r:236 g:143 b:176 
[23]->r:182 g:75 b:117 
[24]->r:189 g:36 b:102 
[25]->r:80 g:21 b:50 
[26]->r:240 g:178 b:208 
[27]->r:207 g:102 b:155 
[28]->r:232 g:200 b:216 
[29]->r:248 g:216 b:232 
[30]->r:207 g:145 b:177 
[31]->r:198 g:61 b:149 
[32]->r:248 g:200 b:232 
[33]->r:235 g:144 b:209 
[34]->r:99 g:55 b:87 
[35]->r:133 g:78 b:118 
[36]->r:213 g:109 b:197 
[37]->r:157 g:108 b:150 
[38]->r:171 g:15 b:156 
[39]->r:137 g:22 b:125 
[40]->r:198 g:71 b:193 
[41]->r:186 g:26 b:181 
[42]->r:208 g:146 b:207 
[43]->r:240 g:179 b:238 
[44]->r:24 g:8 b:24 
[45]->r:236 g:146 b:235 
[46]->r:248 g:200 b:248 
[47]->r:175 g:143 b:175 
[48]->r:232 g:200 b:232 
[49]->r:248 g:216 b:248 
[50]->r:232 g:216 b:232 
[51]->r:248 g:232 b:248 
[52]->r:207 g:177 b:209 
[53]->r:45 g:21 b:48 
[54]->r:208 g:146 b:234 
[55]->r:232 g:200 b:248 
[56]->r:24 g:8 b:40 
[57]->r:176 g:144 b:210 
[58]->r:206 g:180 b:234 
[59]->r:216 g:200 b:232 
[60]->r:232 g:216 b:248 
[61]->r:45 g:22 b:76 
[62]->r:146 g:110 b:200 
[63]->r:216 g:197 b:248 
[64]->r:176 g:147 b:233 
[65]->r:24 g:8 b:56 
[66]->r:45 g:20 b:114 
[67]->r:82 g:54 b:160 
[68]->r:104 g:79 b:188 
[69]->r:42 g:22 b:146 
[70]->r:44 g:23 b:169 
[71]->r:54 g:50 b:77 
[72]->r:20 g:22 b:169 
[73]->r:18 g:20 b:152 
[74]->r:16 g:17 b:136 
[75]->r:15 g:16 b:114 
[76]->r:8 g:8 b:56 
[77]->r:8 g:8 b:40 
[78]->r:8 g:8 b:24 
[79]->r:24 g:24 b:56 
[80]->r:24 g:24 b:40 
[81]->r:200 g:200 b:248 
[82]->r:177 g:177 b:209 
[83]->r:200 g:200 b:232 
[84]->r:216 g:216 b:248 
[85]->r:216 g:216 b:232 
[86]->r:232 g:232 b:248 
[87]->r:141 g:141 b:144 
[88]->r:17 g:19 b:78 
[89]->r:44 g:47 b:170 
[90]->r:42 g:44 b:148 
[91]->r:141 g:143 b:174 
[92]->r:60 g:70 b:184 
[93]->r:139 g:147 b:233 
[94]->r:49 g:56 b:114 
[95]->r:175 g:180 b:232 
[96]->r:102 g:117 b:199 
[97]->r:136 g:146 b:210 
[98]->r:21 g:46 b:170 
[99]->r:20 g:45 b:146 
[100]->r:87 g:106 b:167 
[101]->r:184 g:199 b:248 
[102]->r:18 g:48 b:114 
[103]->r:8 g:24 b:56 
[104]->r:184 g:200 b:232 
[105]->r:200 g:216 b:248 
[106]->r:175 g:176 b:178 
[107]->r:38 g:87 b:163 
[108]->r:145 g:181 b:232 
[109]->r:168 g:200 b:248 
[110]->r:143 g:175 b:211 
[111]->r:8 g:24 b:40 
[112]->r:152 g:199 b:248 
[113]->r:168 g:200 b:232 
[114]->r:184 g:216 b:248 
[115]->r:200 g:216 b:232 
[116]->r:216 g:232 b:248 
[117]->r:207 g:208 b:209 
[118]->r:18 g:49 b:77 
[119]->r:96 g:158 b:217 
[120]->r:12 g:119 b:206 
[121]->r:132 g:195 b:248 
[122]->r:112 g:179 b:228 
[123]->r:90 g:105 b:116 
[124]->r:152 g:200 b:232 
[125]->r:168 g:216 b:248 
[126]->r:58 g:158 b:221 
[127]->r:14 g:143 b:219 
[128]->r:152 g:216 b:248 
[129]->r:184 g:216 b:232 
[130]->r:200 g:232 b:248 
[131]->r:47 g:49 b:50 
[132]->r:134 g:200 b:231 
[133]->r:56 g:138 b:169 
[134]->r:132 g:216 b:248 
[135]->r:97 g:152 b:171 
[136]->r:168 g:216 b:232 
[137]->r:183 g:232 b:247 
[138]->r:152 g:216 b:232 
[139]->r:15 g:122 b:146 
[140]->r:133 g:216 b:231 
[141]->r:150 g:232 b:246 
[142]->r:19 g:45 b:49 
[143]->r:179 g:204 b:207 
[144]->r:8 g:24 b:24 
[145]->r:200 g:248 b:248 
[146]->r:200 g:232 b:232 
[147]->r:216 g:248 b:248 
[148]->r:216 g:232 b:232 
[149]->r:232 g:248 b:248 
[150]->r:141 g:177 b:175 
[151]->r:146 g:202 b:191 
[152]->r:26 g:108 b:74 
[153]->r:198 g:248 b:226 
[154]->r:216 g:248 b:232 
[155]->r:17 g:92 b:52 
[156]->r:181 g:232 b:200 
[157]->r:106 g:161 b:125 
[158]->r:18 g:51 b:21 
[159]->r:138 g:180 b:141 
[160]->r:8 g:29 b:8 
[161]->r:153 g:204 b:153 
[162]->r:232 g:248 b:232 
[163]->r:211 g:232 b:209 
[164]->r:178 g:204 b:173 
[165]->r:80 g:95 b:76 
[166]->r:103 g:146 b:70 
[167]->r:230 g:248 b:216 
[168]->r:208 g:232 b:177 
[169]->r:197 g:209 b:179 
[170]->r:230 g:248 b:200 
[171]->r:145 g:186 b:71 
[172]->r:208 g:233 b:145 
[173]->r:230 g:248 b:184 
[174]->r:48 g:56 b:20 
[175]->r:230 g:248 b:161 
[176]->r:177 g:197 b:76 
[177]->r:211 g:232 b:72 
[178]->r:205 g:219 b:112 
[179]->r:176 g:181 b:139 
[180]->r:180 g:191 b:51 
[181]->r:29 g:30 b:8 
[182]->r:157 g:158 b:53 
[183]->r:207 g:208 b:145 
[184]->r:207 g:206 b:75 
[185]->r:248 g:248 b:168 
[186]->r:232 g:232 b:162 
[187]->r:248 g:248 b:184 
[188]->r:232 g:232 b:184 
[189]->r:248 g:248 b:200 
[190]->r:232 g:232 b:200 
[191]->r:248 g:248 b:216 
[192]->r:232 g:232 b:216 
[193]->r:248 g:248 b:232 
[194]->r:211 g:205 b:52 
[195]->r:245 g:237 b:74 
[196]->r:247 g:238 b:113 
[197]->r:247 g:238 b:145 
[198]->r:90 g:85 b:46 
[199]->r:165 g:158 b:103 
[200]->r:239 g:208 b:32 
[201]->r:135 g:118 b:18 
[202]->r:203 g:188 b:109 
[203]->r:248 g:232 b:168 
[204]->r:229 g:216 b:163 
[205]->r:243 g:204 b:76 
[206]->r:137 g:114 b:49 
[207]->r:248 g:232 b:184 
[208]->r:227 g:216 b:184 
[209]->r:245 g:204 b:113 
[210]->r:248 g:232 b:200 
[211]->r:183 g:126 b:18 
[212]->r:219 g:155 b:42 
[213]->r:246 g:209 b:144 
[214]->r:139 g:116 b:79 
[215]->r:81 g:55 b:18 
[216]->r:248 g:216 b:168 
[217]->r:229 g:200 b:162 
[218]->r:177 g:120 b:50 
[219]->r:135 g:80 b:18 
[220]->r:225 g:156 b:80 
[221]->r:248 g:216 b:184 
[222]->r:232 g:216 b:200 
[223]->r:248 g:232 b:216 
[224]->r:208 g:176 b:145 
[225]->r:182 g:121 b:78 
[226]->r:231 g:161 b:111 
[227]->r:248 g:200 b:168 
[228]->r:182 g:81 b:19 
[229]->r:110 g:52 b:19 
[230]->r:210 g:106 b:44 
[231]->r:227 g:200 b:184 
[232]->r:137 g:79 b:50 
[233]->r:241 g:178 b:145 
[234]->r:248 g:216 b:200 
[235]->r:143 g:49 b:19 
[236]->r:174 g:80 b:50 
[237]->r:248 g:200 b:184 
[238]->r:179 g:49 b:19 
[239]->r:217 g:102 b:94 
[240]->r:183 g:118 b:115 
[241]->r:208 g:139 b:137 
[242]->r:241 g:178 b:176 
[243]->r:28 g:8 b:8 
[244]->r:178 g:80 b:78 
[245]->r:137 g:78 b:78 
[246]->r:236 g:140 b:140 
[247]->r:248 g:200 b:200 
[248]->r:232 g:200 b:200 
[249]->r:248 g:216 b:216 
[250]->r:232 g:216 b:216 
[251]->r:248 g:232 b:232 
[252]->r:248 g:248 b:248 
[253]->r:232 g:232 b:232 
[254]->r:24 g:24 b:24 
[255]->r:8 g:8 b:8
```

EDIT:
added the following:

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(render.program, "colormap"), 1);
```

and now I get proper colors but a very blurry and noisy image.

Comment: Where are the uniforms set and textures bound for drawing?

Comment: sorry, just added the binding/drawing code to the question

Comment: Where do you set the values of uniform variables?

Comment: I don't. Those should be sorted out when calling glActiveTexture according to the position in the shader code.

Comment: I have reverted your last edit because you should not put the solution in the question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions . In my opinion, the original problem (everything is red) and the new problem (everything is blurry) are different problems, even though they're both related to the same part of the program.

Comment: ok sorry about that, but a new question would be very redundant

Comment: (even if I'm wrong about that, it's still not acceptable to update the question to add the solution for the first part. It would be an extra section at the end instead, like "update: I did this and now the first problem is solved but this new problem still happens.")

Comment: ok will do as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,
the problem here was the Use of GL_LINEAR filtering. It would interpolate the texture and create "entry" values that don't map coherently anymore to the original color-map.
Changing it to GL_NEAREST fixed it:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 0):

[You need to](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers) bind the `colormap` uniform to texture unit 1 (which has the colormap texture bound).

You don't need to bind `ourTexture` because 0 is the default value, but you can.

You can do this with (when the program is bound):

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "colormap"), 1);
```

Otherwise, both samplers read from the image texture using texture unit 0.

Comment: thanks, it's getting better, now I get some colors. However the image is very blurred and noisy. I think it might be due to the normalization. How can I get the exact color values instead of normalized  0.0 -1.0 scale?

Comment: @metamatic Are these useful? https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Direct_texel_fetches

Comment: tried with the follwing:
 float color = texture(ourTexture, texCoord).r; 
 fragColor = texelFetch(colormap, ivec2(round(256.0*color),0),0);
but same result (actually i think I'm doing a NEAREST myself)

Comment: If it's more complicated than that, then I think it deserves a separate question. Questions should be about a specific problem, and your specific problem has been solved, and now you have a completely different problem.

Comment: my specific problem is about colormapping in a shader the same way I've described I do in the CPU, and this has not been solved. Thank you for the hint about the uniform but that's only one part of the solution.

Comment: Maybe you should add a screenshot of what it looks like and what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot show the original data due to copyright issues and don't have a testing data set.